# Port forwarding without router access

Tags: networking

I want to have a connection to a PC thats physically beside me but in a different network

I can´t mess with the routers due to them being locked behind a password and the passwords being lost with a password manager file that was corrupted ( Yep i do backups now )

Connection is from Fedora ---> Ubuntu

Do i have to get new routers?

( Messing around and learning networking as i go so the... Primitive setup )

Comment: This isn't really about Ubuntu, but some other network equipment. That said, you may post on [superuser.com](https://superuser.com) for help with regaining access to your router. Normally you can do that via a factory reset or similar.

Comment: Ubuntu is the OS accepting the connection so i figured... Well my bad will keep in mind! Thank you